# Uploading/Downloading file from Artifactory OSS while preserving file permissions

Tags: centos, artifactory, file-permissions

I have a binary file named node_exporter, which has executable file permissions:

```
    -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16834973 Jul 29 08:35 node_exporter
```

I use the Artifactory CLI to upload the file:
`./jfrog rt u node_exporter {repo}/node_exporter`.
And then to download the file:
`./jfrog rt dl {repo}/node_exporter`.

Once downloaded, the file loses executable permissions.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 16834973 Jul 29 08:44 node_exporter
```

I know that using cURL doesn't deal with metadata, but I'm not sure why the official CLI doesn't as well. Is it possible at all to upload/download while preserving file permissions? This is being used in integration with Jenkins, so I would rather not have to set the file permissions after downloading the binary for each build.